# OO way to create objects from their string representation

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I like to keep my design clean and OO: I have an abstract java class (Block) with a method to return a string representation of the object to be able to save it to a file for instance. I also have loader functions (currently external to Block and it's subclasses) to turn a string representation of a object back into the object it was. How do I do this without if, else if, else if, etc... The getIdentifier() method returns a unique string identifying the block type in a 4 letter String. I wish to keep it this way for ease of use later on. This is "srce" for a source block for instance. The string representation is then srce,1,0,1,1 for instance with the parameters in commas defining the state of this specific block.

```
public abstract class Block{
    public abstract String getIdentifier();
    public abstract String getStringRepr();
}
```

I want a polymorphic way of turning a String representation from above into a java object. Right now, defining a new Block type with it's behavior (in other methods) is easy, however the string to object function still needs to be declared elsewhere which bugs me.

Edit: I don't want a different serialisation of this object. I need to be able to produce them using a shorthand, human readable format.

Comment: Can you use an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern)?

Comment: Sounds like you should just use GSON.

Comment: +1 to @trevor-e, I'd use GSON to serialize your object to a JSON string representation, then GSON to deserialize a JSON string representation back into an Object.

Comment: XML does still exist too.

Comment: I want to be able to create these objects using this representation on the commandline. That's why I want to stick to this representation. It's quick and easy to remember. 

Let me rephrase what I really want here. Given a string, I want to instantiate an object of the class identified by that string. And I want to only declare that representation in that class.

Comment: You'll need to write your own custom string parser, specific to your string format, that will translate each string representation into an object. Not very re-usable and much more work than using something that's standardized.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you want an `abstract` method `getStringRepr()` instead of just overriding `toString()` - unless each subclass of `Block` is going to have it's own specific format.

Comment: yes, I've already got one. But that still hasn't answered my question. All I want is to call a constructor of the type associated with the identifying string, and this without defining an explicit map<String, Class> outside of the new Block extension.

Comment: And, yes: toString is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON serialization for that, here is an example of using Jackson:

```
    // create object mapper
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

    // write object to file
    Block block = new SomeBlockImpl();
    File outputFile = new File("output location goes here");
    objectMapper.writeValue(outputFile, block);

    // read object from file
    File inputFile = new File("input location goes here");
    Block savedBlock = objectMapper.readValue(inputFile, Block.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done it: I've added yet another abstract method which registers the block's identifier with a Class higher up. This maps the identifier to the specific Block class thus allowing me to call the correct constructor without having to if else my way through all options for the identifier.